# Google Security Center Python API Failing

Tags: python, api, security, center

I am trying to retrieve findings from Google Security Center using the Python API. I have installed the python libraries, set up a service account, generated a key and when I try to get the finding or any client functions I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./find.py", line 12, in <module>
    finding_result_iterator = client.list_findings(all_sources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/securitycenter_v1/gapic/security_center_client.py", line 1532, in list_findings
    self.transport.list_findings,
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'list_findings'
```

I am using the code example from here:
https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-api-list-findings

Using Python 3.6, I have the json key file in the client create and my organization id. Any idea why I can't get any client functions to work?

Comment: How are you initializing the client? It looks like you might be passing in a string as the `transport` argument.

Comment: I am passing the API Key in as the argument for authentication like this client = securitycenter.SecurityCenterClient("gcp-sc.json")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am passing the API Key in as the argument for authentication like this
>
> `client = securitycenter.SecurityCenterClient("gcp-sc.json")`

If you have a file called `gcp-sc.json` with the Google credential data, either

- set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to that path, then initialize the client without configuration (`SecurityCenterClient()`), it'll pick that up
- or if you need to explicitly name the file,  `SecurityCenterClient.from_service_account_json('gcp-sc.json')` ought to do the trick.

You can also pass in a custom credentials object (see [the docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html)) as `SecurityCenterClient(credentials=...)`